# variable clock generation in verilog using task

Tags: verilog, clock

I have used following code to generate clock (whichever value I pass through task it will create that frequency), but the code only works if I use `CLKSEL_global = clksel_local` (i.e. blocking assignment) but that creates delta delay.

How do I generate variable clock without introducing delta delay? Is their another way of using a task. I am using task so that I can pass real values

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module tb();
  real CLKSEL_global;

  reg CLK7;


  new dut(clk,clk_out);

  task task_CLOCK;
    input real clksel_local;
    begin
      CLKSEL_global = clksel_local;
    end
  endtask

  initial begin
    CLK7 = 0;
    forever begin
      #(500.0/CLKSEL_global) CLK7 = 1;
      #(500.0/CLKSEL_global) CLK7 = 0;
    end
  end


  initial begin
    task_CLOCK(340.0);
  end

  initial begin
    #100 $finish ;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: ya its not the part and can be removed

Comment: Just need to also remove the line ` new dut(clk,clk_out);` then the question is all about `CLK7`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution feels like a nasty hack but I think achieves the requirement. When changing the Clock frequency it will change on the next edge, but allows `@(posedge clk)` to be used for the edge you want to change it on. The change is actually `1ns` after the positive edge.

Normally the you would set the frequency and allow it to take effect on the edge giving a full cycle of setup.

[image: Timing Diagram]

```
module tb();
  real CLKSEL_global = 500;
  reg clk;

  task task_CLOCK;
    input real clksel_local;
    begin
      CLKSEL_global <= clksel_local;
    end
  endtask

  initial begin
    #1ns;        
    clk = 1'b0;
    forever begin  
      #((500.0ns/CLKSEL_global) -1ns) clk = ~clk;
    end
  end

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;

    task_CLOCK(1);
    repeat(2)
      @(posedge clk);

    task_CLOCK(2);
    repeat(2)
      @(posedge clk);

    $finish ;
  end
endmodule
```

Working copy of above on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/PHv).

Comment: real CLKSEL_global = 1 creates a problem that for first 500ns clk = 0 then toggling starts

Comment: thanks for answering ,,what i am trying to do is creating the task so that clk frequency can be changed like task_clock(340.0)   #40 task_clock(170.0) , that is getting desired frequency but delta delay in task creates skew which is problem for me,i m trying to create a general clock generator where i pass value and it generates clock

Comment: @ra-one re-written answer. see if this is closer.

Comment: Why `#1ns` is used in forever loop ? Can I remove that by modifying next line to `#((500.0ns/CLKSEL_global) clk = ~clk;`.

Comment: @Jithindid you try it? The `#1ns;` could be before the for loop but without some initial delay the division is by 0 so the sim locks up. Golden Rule of Verilog simulation, never do anything at time 0.